# Custom Control Overriding Command Button

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I am trying to create a custom command button that defaults width and height to specific settings.  I have the following code:

```
public partial class myCommandButton : Button
{
    public magCommandButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    [DefaultValue(840)]
    public override int Width
    {
        get 
        {
            return base.Width;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Width = value;
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue(340)]
    public override int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Height;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Height = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

However, it won't compile because it tells me that I can not override Width or Height.  Can anyone tell me if I'm approaching this wrongly, or if there's a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width and Height are not virtual members (check Control class in [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx)), so the simpliest way is to override DefaultSize property:

```
        protected override Size DefaultSize
        {
            get
            {
                return new Size(840, 340);
            }
        }
```

You can also use [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28VS.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier), but for this example I recommend to override DefaultSize. If you check Control class in Reflector you will see, that Height and Width use a lot of internal/private members. So I don't that implementing all those things is a good idea.
Just use DefaultSize property.

Comment: You don't necessarly need reflector to check classes methods/definitions/modifiers/etc.
You can simply view the class metadata in visual studio by clicking "Go to definition" in the context menu over the word "Control" or whatever type you need to check ;)

Comment: Well... I don't like to view metadata only. 
I'm using resharper + scout plugin and it's great. New reflector has some features and you can go directly to this tool from code and check the implementation, but scout is better I think.
But new Resharper (v 5.0) is the best - you can watch compiled assemblies source code directly from VS :D